# response is giving all invoices while fetching invoice by id

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

i want to fetch data by id (invoice by id) by when i run my code then it gives me all data(all invoices), can anyone plz check where is the problem, i want to fetch data by id (invoice by id) by when i run my code then it gives me all data(all invoices), can anyone plz check where is the problem,
its in symfony

code:

```
  public function getInvoice(Request $request)
  {
  $response = null;

  $status = [
      0 => 'APPROVED',
      1 => 'REJECTED'
    ];

     try {
      $this->isGraned($request);
      $jwt = new JWT();

      $rawRequest = file_get_contents("php://input");
      $decodedData = $jwt->decode($rawRequest, 

       $this->getSecretKey($request));
      $userId = isset($decodedData->userId) ? $decodedData->userId :  
      null;

      $iObj = new Invoice();

      $invoiceRepository = $em->getRepository(Invoice::class);

      $user = '';
      if ($userId != null)
      {
          $userRepo = $em->getRepository(User::class);
          $user = $userRepo->getUserByAuth($userId);
      }

   $invoices = $invoiceRepository->getInvoiceByUser($user->getId());

      $data = [];
      foreach ($users as $user) {
          $status = "";
          if(isset($user['status']))
          {
              $status = $invoice['status'];
          }
          $data[] = [
              'invoiceId' => $invoice['invoiceId'],
              'dateTime' => $invoice['dateTime'],
              'amount' => $invoice['amount'],
              'status' => $status,
              'fileUrl' => $invoice['fileUrl']
              ];
      }

      $rawResponse = $data;

      $rawResponse = $jwt->encode((object) ['data' => $rawResponse],       
$this->getSecretKey($request));

$response = new JsonResponse($rawResponse, 200, array(
    'Content-Type' => $request->getMimeType('json'),
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
      ));
  } catch (AccessDeniedHttpException $ex){
      $data = $ex->getMessage();
      if(!empty($mobileReq)) {
        $data = $jwt->encode((object)$data, 
 $this->getSecretKry($request));
      }
      $response = new Response($data, 401);
  } catch (\Exception $ex) {
    $data = $ex->getMessage();
      if(!empty($mobileReq)) {
        $data = $jwt->encode((object)$data, 
$this->getSecretKry($request));
      }
      $response = new Response($data, 500);
  }
  return $response;
  }
```

Comment: `$invoiceRepository` is never used in this code. You're also using `$invoice` without ever setting a value for it. I'm a bit baffled by this code, frankly; does it even work at all? It should be generating a parse error.

Comment: @ceejayoz sorry, edited now plz check again

Comment: Looking at `$invoices = $invoiceRepository->getInvoiceByUser($user->getId());` your issue likely originates from the repository method itself returning all invoices (instead of one).

Add your `getInvoiceByUser` repository method to the question, please.

Comment: Aren't you sure of what framework you're using?

Comment: @cyberdev The code still doesn't make sense; in `$em = $app['orm.em'];`, `$app` is undefined, and `$invoice` is still undefined in your edit; `$invoice` and `$invoices` aren't the same. I think, for starters, you need to take off the try/catch; I think you're hiding a bunch of errors in the `catch (\Exception $ex)`.